# iisexpress.exe started crashing with Access Violation in IsLocalRequest call

Tags: iis-express

with the new 171010-1400 Windows build and Visual Studio Update 4 my previously working config went haywire. As I see from the windbg output, somehow iisexpress.exe fails on the first or the second request, I guess it is in connection with setting a cookie. 
All I see from the debug is the following:

```
ModLoad: 00007ff9`417a0000 00007ff9`417cb000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
18312 w3wphost!W3WP_HOST::IncrementMessages [w3wphost.cxx @ 4073]:IncrementMessages called
(4a30.4788): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\IIS Express\IISUTIL2.dll - 
IISUTIL2!IsLocalRequest+0x2e:
00007ff9`02766d5e 0fb702          movzx   eax,word ptr [rdx] ds:00000000`00000000=????
```

Where can I get more information about this IsLocalRequest call? I guess IISExpress.exe is not open source.

Update1: I think the IISUTIL dll is not on the symbols server:

```
BGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        c:\temp\localsymbols\ntdll.pdb\186E113737814D3E2749831F5FE67D621\ntdll.pdb
Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\temp\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv*c:\temp\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*c:\temp\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x16
         c:\temp\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         iisutil2.pdb
         AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\temp\localsymbols\iisutil2.pdb\AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671\iisutil2.pdb - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\temp\localsymbols\iisutil2.pdb\AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671\iisutil2.pd_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: c:\temp\localsymbols\iisutil2.pdb\AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/iisutil2.pdb/AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671/iisutil2.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/iisutil2.pdb/AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671/iisutil2.pd_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/iisutil2.pdb/AA5E50675E9E42B0950F0C58B916E2671/file.ptr

SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisutil2.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: iisutil2.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\IIS Express\IISUTIL2.dll - 
DBGHELP: IISUTIL2 - export symbols
```

Comment: Are you also getting an event logged?

Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe,
version: 10.0.14358.1000, 
time stamp: 0x574fc56b
Faulting module name: IISUTIL2.dll, 
version: 10.0.14358.1000, 
time stamp: 0x574fc585
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0002728b
Faulting process ID: 0xeec
Faulting application start time: 0x01d34762efa5ff0f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\IISUTIL2.dll

Comment: @Access IT: yes, that's why I started debugging :)

Comment: What controls are you running? I could get it working fine until I included a TELERIK control and then I had problems (Access Violation) even on a clean web application. I was able to use IIS (not express) after performing the usual tedious tasks with it to get it working.

Comment: a big MVC application with multiple components. Everything is working until I try to set a cookie, or try a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/523):
1) this is a known regression in httpd.sys, soon to be fixed in a developer build
2) IIS Express pdbs will not be published, it's a "conscious decision" on their side

Comment: I still get this issue today. If I reboot my pc it then goes away. But If I reboot Vs it still happens.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the root of the problem was an `StackoverflowException`. There was no message in my output window which indicated this problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what was the error, I am getting the same error and also the message stack overflow. I have also put a question on StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70376351/stack-overflow-on-form-submit

Comment: @AsadUllah In my case, a property getter return itself instead of its private attribute member, which resulted in an endless loop by recursion.

Answer (score 4):

For historical purposes. This happened to me because there was a code error.

In my case, an attempt to convert from one type to another using the
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(model), but without set the mapping definition.
Also this call was made within an implicit operator:

```
public static implicit operator DestinyType (ModelType model)
{
      return Mapper.Map <DestinyType> (model);
}
```

My alternative was to use something like:

```
     public static implicit operator DestinyType (ModelType model)
     {
         var mapper = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor <ModelType, DestinyType> ();

         if (mapper == null)
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException ();
         }

         return Mapper.Map <DestinyType> (model);
     }
```

Comment: In my case, it was crashing when casting enum to a string.

Comment: Code error at runtime : Overloads with optional parameters. Calling an overload with method of same name, but not entering optional params > Accidental recursion, whoops, was wondering why it repeatedly hit the breakpoint, ha! (sample code silliness below) that is the end of my dev confessional ------------

    public class Duh
    {
        void CallMySelf(object x, object y) { CallMySelf(x, y); /* should have put in third property to avoid recursion, or name methods differently*/ }
        void CallMySelf(object x, object y, object z = null) { /*where I meant to pass it*/ }
    }

Comment: I had this problem with AutoMapper.Collection 6.0.0 and AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.0.0, when mapping an IList. Upgrading to 7.0.1 and 8.1.0 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, IIS express shut down with this error. After scratching my head for a while, i found out that it came from a wrong implementation of IDisposable in one of my classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to having a two getters depend on each other's value in some cases.

**E.g:**

**propA** sometimes depends on **propB's** value

**and**

**PropB** sometimes depends on on **propA's** value

This causes a recursive infinite call to the properties in some cases. This causes iisExpress to hang for a while as it spits out a massive exception to the stack, then errors out with
"iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'"

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this error message because I had named my view 'View', changing it to 'Details' solved the issue.