# Stack Overflow on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, http-post, stack-overflow

I am creating two login forms, Razor Page,

The Page Model `Login.cshtml.cs` is as follow

```
        public void OnGet()
        {
 
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Admin Admin { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public Member Member { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPostManager()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../Index");
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostMember()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../Index");
        }
```

This is the Login.cshtml file

```
<div class="col">

    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Admin.Id" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="Admin.Name" />
        <button type="button" asp-page_handler="Manager">Login</button>
    </form>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Member.Id" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="Member.Name" />
        <button type="button" asp-page_handler="Member">Login</button>
    </form>


</div>
```

The problem is When I click the Login button for Member, it redirects successfully to Index Page.
But when I click on login for admin, the web application crashes and It shows error StackOverflow [just the keyword].

I have tried;

1. deleting the bin and obj.
2. deleting the IISExpress folder and .vs folder
3. restart the visual studio
4. restarting the computer
5. deleting the %temp% file

but no solution.

[note: this is the simplified code from the original file, the original file contain more CSS and icons]

Comment: First of all, just as a small tip to do things right, Member and Admin could been handled by the same class with a property which dedicates what role they have if you dont want to implement a role system. Less doubled code blocks but you dont have to.

Can you maybe give us insight on whats happening in the index page? It seems to behave differently depending on what object is filled.

Comment: Simple Index page , I haven't changed anything in Index

Comment: Okay, im very sure its not quite on the code you showed us. Except from the points that `asp-page_handler` should be `asp-page-handler` and your button `type="button"` should be `type="submit"` since your methods are called `OnPost...`. Is there any piece of logic involved except that?

Answer (score -1):

```
    <form method="post" class="login-form">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span
                                                class="fa fa-user"></span></div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="FirstName" placeholder="FirstName"
                                            required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><span
                                                class="fa fa-lock"></span></div>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="LastName"
                                            placeholder="LastName" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn"
                                            class="btn form-control btn-primary rounded submit px-3">Go!</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

    //Login.cshtml.cs
    
    [BindProperty]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest
            {
                FirstName = FirstName,
                LastName = LastName,
            };

            .
            .
            .
            
            if (..)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./Home");
            }

            
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: I think you can improve your answer a little bit to make it easier to read. What exactly did you change and why? You used different layouts and objects than OP as well as different functions. Help us understand your decision.